# repaint() Method in Java

Tags: java, awt, repaint

I am playing around with the Java graphics class a little bit and I was just wondering--when is it necessary to call the method `repaint()`? I tried commenting it out and it didn't seem to affect my output GUI. I've seen it used a lot in Java GUI code that I've read, though. Would anyone mind explaining when to use it and when not to use it?

Answer (score 1):

It's never really necessary in most swing applications, because they handle it automatically (for common operations such as changing text values on buttons and adding data to a list box).

Generally, it's only if you've made some sort of change that swing won't automatically pick up - for example, you're not using a layout manager and are resizing components manually (because normally the layout manager repaints its components when necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The `repaint()` refreshes the view (component), so whenever you make any change on the component, you must call it. For instance, if you rotate the graphical component, you must make a call to `repaint()` in order to see the change on the containing component

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I am actually trying to make my graphic such that when a user clicks on the x-axis (it's a sound speed plot) that the graph will zoom in on that particular part of the graph. I am a little stuck as to how to do so. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is what I'd probably do: Get the coordonate of the point i clicked, given by `getX()` and `getY()`. Then create a graphic **g** that will be the area I want to show and `repain(g)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your application, you "paint" your GUI.

You need to call `repaint()` when you want to re-draw your GUI because you have changed something inside.

If you want to delete a button, you need to remove it (or make it invisible) then you need to call `validate()` or `repaint()` to re-calculate (re-draw) the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The only stuff I can think of:

```
    new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    while (ClassName.this.isVisible()) {
        ClassName.this.updateStatusLabel();
        ClassName.this.validate();
        ClassName.this.repaint(50L);
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        Log.log(e);
        }
    }
    }
}.start();
```

Suppose you have the above code in the constructor of a JDialog. What *updateStatusLabel* does is checking a boolean variable, either public or settable through a method, and set the icon of a JLabel in base to such boolean. If you don't validate and repaint the GUI, the modification won't be shown until another event, most likely an user-triggered one, is thrown. And, if the user is waiting for the label to show a certain icon because of, let's say, it indicated if a device is reachable through the Internet, he/she'll never interact (or, at least, you're delaying interactions so much).